# Using filters to track hits for multiple URLs

Tags: google-analytics

We have a large website that is split up into groups of organisations with a number of micro-sites. We would like to provide one organisation within a group with their own set of data and I am having troubling getting the filtering working.

I think my main problem is I have 2 include filters. According to the documentation:

> "If you apply multiple Include Filters, the hit must match every applied Include Filter in order to save the hit."

Our website urls would go something like this: https://[host]/[group]/[site]/[params]. I would like to track the following, given that this client (id 9) is in group "foo":

- https://mysite.com/foo/live/default.aspx?id=9
- https://mysite.com/foo/live/?id=9
- https://mysite.com/foo/reporting/9/*

so that any hits on those urls would be captured for this particular client.

Our 2 current filters (type="Include") are as follows:

- /foo/Reporting/9/
- /foo/[^\?]*\?id=9

but these do not seem to track everything we think they should. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By the time the first filter is done there is nothing left for the second filter to match - the first filter throws everything away that does not match (that's what Google means by "the hit must match every applied Include Filter").

I would suggest you first use an advanced filter to transform your urls so they follow all the same pattern (i.e. grab the value from the query parameter and append it to the url path) and then apply the include filter. I'm pretty certain that would be easier than trying to include different url structures (if you need help with the filters holler away in the comments, but the example given in the advanced filters interface should give you a clue how this works).

Comment: Cool - I've tried with one filter: /foo/[\w]*/[^\d]*9. I'll give it a cpl of days to see what gets logged.